# Convergence of product over all primes

Tags: convergence-divergence, prime-numbers, infinite-product

How can we find the values of $x$ for which 
$$\prod_{p \text{ prime}}{1-\frac{x^2}{p^2}}$$
converges? I know that this product
$$\prod_{p \text{ prime}}{1+\frac{x^2}{p^2}}$$
converges if and only if
$$\sum_{p \text{ prime}}{\frac{x^2}{p^2}}$$
converges, and since
$$\sum_{p \text{ prime}}{\frac{x^2}{p^2}}=\sum_{p \text{ prime}}{x^2\frac{1}{p^2}}=x^2\sum_{p \text{ prime}}{\frac{1}{p^2}}$$
we can see that this sum is a number $x^2$ times primezeta(2), which converges, so the product converges for all $x$. Is this correct? Is there a way to adapt this to the original product? Any help would be appriciated!

Comment: I'm not sure where $1+x^2/p^2$ criterion comes from, but could you not just make the replacement $-x^2$ for $x^2$? That is,
$$
1+\frac{x^2}{p^2}=1-\frac{-x^2}{p^2}.
$$

Comment: No because it should ba 1+a(n) where a(n) is always positive.
http://cornellmath.wordpress.com/2008/01/26/convergence-of-infinite-products/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should converge for all $x$; apart from finitely many terms at the outset all terms are in $(0,1)$ so the sequence from that point on is monotonic and bounded by zero.  The partial products are a monotonic bounded sequence of real numbers, which must therefore converge.

Comment: An interesting question arising is whether the limit is then nonzero.